# Is it possible to exhibit a collection of sets

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, convergence-divergence, summation

Let a subset $D$ of the natural numbers be called convergent or divergent when the associated series $\sum_{d \in D} \frac{1}{d}$ converges or diverges.

Define a topology on $\Bbb{N}$ by defining the closed sets to be convergent sets.  Then divergent sets are not compact in this topology.

Proof:  Another definition of a compact space is that any collection of closed sets with the finite intersection property have a non-empty intersection.  So I want to exhibit an infinite family of convergent subsets of a divergent set $D$ such that any finite collection has non-empty intersection yet all of them intersected does not.  It seems like it can be done.   What do you guys think?

Seems way hard though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some unused information in the hypothesis.  It should be:

The space presented in which the closed sets are convergent sets has the property that no infinite subset is compact.

*Proof*. Let $E$ be an infinite subset of $\Bbb{N}$.  Since $E$ is infinite, there exists a subsequence ${e_n}$ in $E$ such that $e_n > n^2$ and hence $\sum_{i \geq 1} \frac{1}{e_i} \lt \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$ and converges.  Put the sequence in a vertical list and next to each element, write down its number (n) in binary.  In the binary number $n$ a $1$ at digit position $j$ represents element $e_n$ being in convergent set $j$ that we're constructing.  Now clearly every sequence constructed thusly is also convergent being a subsequence of $\{e_n\}$.  And also every finite collection shares an element.  And if you intersecting all of them obviously gives you an empty set as each row contains a $0$.  QED